how to get actual group name from statusBarNotification in NotificationListenerService?
I am reading notifications using NotificatioListnerService , all things are working fine , but extracting a group name from title is tricky sometimes.
I got title from notifiction bundle using
var notification = sbn?.notification
var title = NotificationCompat.getContentTitle(notification!!).toString()

or
val title= bundle?.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE).toString()

or
from messegingStyle etc.
but got title like : Group (x massages) : ~ Sender  // here x is number
i am talking about only Group messages , in personal no any problem
but actual group name is : Group
I can split group name and sender by : , that's not a problem
problem is that (x messages) is added ,
here i can remove using regex expression , but on which condition i will have to remove , may be group name itself contain (x messages) , like in notification title we got : Group (x messages) (x messages),
I want to remove only if it is added
I have used a condition to remove
I got messages size in notification,
val messageList = bundle?.getParcelableArray(NotificationCompat.EXTRA_MESSAGES)?.size

or

val messageList = NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.extractMessagingStyleFromNotification(fullTitlee!!)?.messages?.size
messageList?.let {
    if (it > 1) {
       title = removeLastMessagesFromText(title.toString())
   }
}

and its working fine, because its generally added (x messages) , when size is greater of 1 , in rare condition or glitch its not working as expected , when i observe , I saw , when messageSize is 1 , still added additional (x messages) in title
I have compare that bundles , but found nothing different
I have also got title/conversationTitle every possible title which i can have added that (x messages) additionaly
Now i want to get perfect reason , when (x messages) is added , so i can remove easily
